# Find opposite side length of right triangle inside ellipsoid

Tags: triangles, ellipsoids

Given an ellipsoid and angle theta (illustrated below), what is the equation to find the length of the opposite side, shown in red. The hypotenuse connects at the ellipsoid center and perimeter.

For the ellipsoid parameters, you can use the WGS84 reference ellipsoid. Would appreciate a complete example so I can verify that I understand your description of the solution.

Thanks very much in advance

[image: ellipsoid with interior right triangle]

Comment: Well, if the center is the origin and the point on the ellipse is $(x,y)$ then the red line has length $|x|$, right?  If you imagined the data being given in some other way, please specify.

Comment: I don't have (x, y), I have angle theta, so how can I find (x, y)?

Comment: There is no $\theta$ in your picture.  We can't guess from your picture what data defines the ellipse and your points.  Please edit for clarity.

Comment: WGS 84, as mentioned, provides the reference ellipsoid. I don't understand ellipsoid mathematical definitions, I'm sorry.  is the angle of the triangle so you can assume 0 <=  <= 90.

Comment: It's the elliptical approximation of Earth. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_ellipsoid

Comment: Oh, you are referring to Geospatial coordinates?  So this ellipse is actually on a sphere? From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740192/overview-for-converting-local-plane-coordinates-to-wgs84) one sees that conversions are non-trivial.

Comment: Note:  my first comment is not correct (unless the ellipse is very small) since I had incorrectly assumed this was a planar ellipse.

Comment: Yes, it is a planar ellipse. It should represent a meridian of the earth, or in other words, think of it as the perimeter of a cross-section of the earth, passing perfectly through the center and both poles.

Comment: Well, I don't know geospatial coordinate systems.  If this is a planar ellipse with center at the origin (in the appropriate plane) then a typical parameterization would be $(a\cos(\theta), b\sin (\theta))$ from which one can read off the two lengths.  (note that this $\theta$ might not exactly coincide with yours...they might differ by $\frac {\pi}2$).

Comment: I don't completely understand, but what does a and b represent in this equation?

Comment: $a,b$ are constants, the lengths of the major and minor semi-axes.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I understand now, I've seen that in the WGS 84 specs.

Comment: Thank you, I think I know how to do this now. Thanks so much!

Comment: Good luck! $\quad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ellipse with nonempty interior and centered at the origin is the image of a unit circle under an invertible linear transformation. Formally, if $A = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ is the matrix that represents this transformation, then the set
$$
E = \{ Ax ~|~ \lVert x\rVert^2 = 1\},
$$
is an ellipsoid.

Let $x=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ be a vector on the unit circle. If the ellipse is not rotated, then the matrix is just $A=\begin{pmatrix}w&0\\0&h\end{pmatrix}$, where $w,h$ are the nonzero "width" and "height" of the ellipse respectively (or, the lengths of its principle axes). So $y = Ax = (w\cos\theta, h\sin\theta)$, which contains the lengths of right-angled sides (you're interested in $w\cos\theta$).